# How to filter array of elements in JMESPath with Azure CLI

Tags: json, azure-cli, jmespath

I am total newbie in JMESPath parsing.
`az network lb inbound-nat-rule list --resource-group MYRG --lb-name MYLB` is returning below output and I would like filter only `backendIpConfiguration.id` and `backendPort` in the response.

Below response in have array of elements.

```
[
  {
    "backendIpConfiguration": {
      "applicationGatewayBackendAddressPools": null,
      "applicationSecurityGroups": null,
      "etag": null,
      "gatewayLoadBalancer": null,
      "id": "/subscriptions/XXXX/XXX/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/XXX/ipConfigurations/XXXX",
      "loadBalancerBackendAddressPools": null,
      "loadBalancerInboundNatRules": null,
      "name": null,
      "primary": null,
      "privateIpAddress": null,
      "privateIpAddressVersion": null,
      "privateIpAllocationMethod": null,
      "privateLinkConnectionProperties": null,
      "provisioningState": null,
      "publicIpAddress": null,
      "resourceGroup": "MYRG01",
      "subnet": null,
      "type": null,
      "virtualNetworkTaps": null
    },
    "backendPort": 1367,
    "enableFloatingIp": false,
    "enableTcpReset": false,
    "etag": "W/\"XXXXX-1173-49ad-8d1f-40347c00d88a\"",
    "frontendIpConfiguration": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/XXXX/XXX/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/XXX/ipConfigurations/XXXX",
      "resourceGroup": "MYRG01"
    },
    "frontendPort": 1367,
    "id": "/subscriptions/XXXX/XXX/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/XXX/ipConfigurations/XXXX",
    "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 5,
    "name": "rule1",
    "protocol": "Tcp",
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "resourceGroup": "MYRG01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/inboundNatRules"
  },
  {
    "backendIpConfiguration": {
      "applicationGatewayBackendAddressPools": null,
      "applicationSecurityGroups": null,
      "etag": null,
      "gatewayLoadBalancer": null,
      "id": "/subscriptions/XXXX/XXX/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/XXX/ipConfigurations/XXXX",
      "loadBalancerBackendAddressPools": null,
      "loadBalancerInboundNatRules": null,
      "name": null,
      "primary": null,
      "privateIpAddress": null,
      "privateIpAddressVersion": null,
      "privateIpAllocationMethod": null,
      "privateLinkConnectionProperties": null,
      "provisioningState": null,
      "publicIpAddress": null,
      "resourceGroup": "MYRG02",
      "subnet": null,
      "type": null,
      "virtualNetworkTaps": null
    },
    "backendPort": 3006,
    "enableFloatingIp": false,
    "enableTcpReset": false,
    "etag": "W/\"XXXX-1173-49ad-8d1f-40347c00d88a\"",
    "frontendIpConfiguration": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/XXXX/XXX/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/XXX/ipConfigurations/XXXX",
      "resourceGroup": "MYRG02"
    },
    "frontendPort": 3006,
    "id": "/subscriptions/XXXX/XXX/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/XXX/ipConfigurations/XXXX",
    "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 5,
    "name": "rule2",
    "protocol": "Tcp",
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "resourceGroup": "MYRG02",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/inboundNatRules"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering in JMESPath is quite simple, and the documentation is pretty straight forward for [filters and multiselect hashes](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#filters-and-multiselect-hashes).

In here, a simple query like:

```
[].{backendIpConfigurationId: backendIpConfiguration.id, backendPort: backendPort}
```

Will give you the filtered JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "backendIpConfigurationId": "/subscriptions/XXXX/XXX/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/XXX/ipConfigurations/XXXX",
    "backendPort": 1367
  },
  {
    "backendIpConfigurationId": "/subscriptions/XXXX/XXX/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/XXX/ipConfigurations/XXXX",
    "backendPort": 3006
  }
]
```

Containing only the informations you are looking for.